# ReactJS - embedding custom element in a custom element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, reactive-programming, typeerror

I just started to learn ReactJS and encountered a problem that I can't solve.

I'm creating a basic application for TV Shows. I have a bootstrap tab for every season of a show and within this tab I want to list all the episodes of the selected season. The problem is that I have to create the tabs in a loop, and within this loop I should have another loop for the episodes.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
EpisodeCards(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            This should contain the details of the episodes
        </div>
    )
}

SeasonTabs(props) {
    console.log('Seasons: ', props.seasons)
    let tabs = [];
    let episodes = [];
    let currentSeason = 1;
    let id;
    let aria;
    for(let season of props.seasons) {
        episodes = [];
        id="nav-season" + currentSeason;
        aria = "nav-season" + currentSeason + "-tab";
        tabs.push(<div className="tab-pane fade" id={id} role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby={aria}><this.EpisodeCards episodes={season}></this.EpisodeCards></div>);

        currentSeason++;
    }
    return (
        <div className="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
           {tabs}
        </div>
    )
}
```

For this I am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'EpisodeCards' of undefined
```

How can this be done in the 'react way'? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are both functions reside inside same class ?

Comment: Yes, in the same React.Component,

Comment: change `SeasonTabs(props)` to `SeasonTabs = (props) =>` let me know if it works

Comment: Actually it did. Wow. Thanks. Can you tell me what's the difference between the 2 declarations?

Comment: @KendiBalazs because by default javascript doesn't bind function, this is `Javascript` behavior not react, and arrow functions don't have this keyword that is why `this` refer to owner class  or component. you can use composition it will be more appropriate to use `EpisodeCards` later in other places  and you don't need `this` keyword in `JSX` if you use composition instead of nested component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
SeasonTabs(props)
```

to

```
SeasonTabs = (props) =>
```

You want to access a class property using `this` but by default its not binded to the function (ES5 only) by creating the functions using arrow `() =>`(new ES6 syntax) it automatically bind `this` to the function.

For Example:

```
class Test extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        this.testFn= this.testFn.bind(this);
    }

    testFn(){
        console.log(this); //will output
    }
    testFn2(){
        console.log(this); // undefined
    }
    testFn3 = () =>{
        console.log(this); //will output
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs is all about **components**, **everything is component**. If a function return a react element or Custom element then is a component.

You are *creating a functional component inside of a class component*, while this approach may work but this is not appropriate way to make component.

- It is better to use composition, your code will be more clear, easier
  to read, better maintainability and you can use component in other
  components.

My solution:

```
function EpisodeCards(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            This should contain the details of the episodes
        </div>
    )
}



SeasonTabs(props) {
    console.log('Seasons: ', props.seasons)
    let tabs = [];
    let episodes = [];
    let currentSeason = 1;
    let id;
    let aria;
    for(let season of props.seasons) {
        episodes = [];
        id="nav-season" + currentSeason;
        aria = "nav-season" + currentSeason + "-tab";
        //There is no need for this keyword
        tabs.push(<div className="tab-pane fade" id={id} role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby={aria}><EpisodeCards episodes={season}/></div>);

        currentSeason++;
    }
    return (
        <div className="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
           {tabs}
        </div>
    )
}
```